# spark count and filtered count in same query

Tags: sql, apache-spark, count, apache-spark-sql

In SQL something like

```sql
SELECT  count(id), sum(if(column1 = 1, 1, 0)) from groupedTable
```

could be formulated to perform a count of the total records as well as filtered records in a single pass.

How can I perform this in spark-data-frame API? i.e. without needing to join back one of the counts to the original data frame.

Comment: Have you tried to run this query with CASE ... WHEN?

Comment: you can register the dataframe as temp table using  `registerTempTable` and as suggested by @T.Gawęda use the CASE ... WHEN statement inthe sql query.

Comment: I know that should work. But is it possible to stay in the more typesafe scala-spark-dataframe api?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can use typed API: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `count` for both cases:

```
df.select(count($"id"), count(when($"column1" === 1, true)))
```

If column is `nullable` you should correct for that (for example with `coalesce` or `IS NULL`, depending on the desired output).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using spark with hive as hive supports sum if() functionality of SQL

First you need to create hive table on top of your data using below code

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hive_Test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
//Creation of hive context      
val hsc = new HiveContext(sc)

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

hsc.sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp (id INT, name STRING)")

hsc.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'examples/src/main/resources/test.txt' INTO TABLE emp")


hsc.sql("""select count(id), SUM(v)
from (
select id, IF(name=1, count(*), 0) AS v
from emp
where id>0
group by id,name
) t2""")
```