# Count & Filter in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In spark often one performs a filter operations before using a map, to make sure that the map is possible. See the example below:

```
bc_ids = sc.broadcast(ids)
new_ids = users.filter(lambda x: x.id in ids.value).map(lambda x: ids.value[x])
```

If you want to know how many users you filtered out, how can you do this efficiently? So I would prefer not to use:

```
count_before = users.count()
new_ids = users.filter(lambda x: x.id in ids.value).map(lambda x: ids.value[x])
count_after = new_ids .count()
```

The question is related to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003609/spark-count-and-filtered-count-in-same-query) but in contrast is not about spark SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In spark often one performs a filter operations before using a map, to
>   make sure that the map is possible.

The reason to  perform filter() before map() is to process only necessary data.

Answer to your question

```
val base = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))    
println(base.filter { _.==(7) }.count())
println(base.filter { !_.==(7) }.count())
```

First one will give you filtered result and second line will give you how many values are filtered.if you are working against cached and partitioned data, then this could be done effectively.